# Match two columns on different sheets and post back some columns to third sheet using formula

Tags: google-sheets

Column A of Elements sheet has Ids. Column B of Connections sheet has Ids 
I need to match on these two columns and post back columns 2, 4, 6 of the Elements sheet to a third sheet

I am trying this formula but I am unable to get it to work, there is no error but nothing is returned

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(vlookup(Elements!A1:A893, Connections!B1:B893, {2,4,6}, 0)))
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The IFERROR will be stopping any error messages being shown.  One of these alternative methods might work:

`=query(Elements!A:F, "select B,D,F where A matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|",1,Connections!B1:B893)&"'")`

`=filter({Elements!B:B,Elements!D:D,Elements!F:F},match(Elements!A:A,Connections!B1:B893,0))`

Comment: Is it good practice to add `ArrayFormula` to formulas.  I am unclear on this. Thanks

Comment: Arrayformula is only needed when you want a formula to be applied to a range of cells rather than just a single cell.  In your original formula, it would be correct to use an arrayformula with VLOOKUP across cells A1:A893.  However, QUERY and FILTER outputs are already arrays in their own right so do not use arrayformula.  Bear in mind as well that not all Sheet functions work with arrayformula e.g. INDEX